# Change size of view and move the surrounding views along

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation

I have a view that I want to change the size of with animation. Below that view are other views that I want to move accordingly.

I have created a new project just so simplify this for me to get this function to work properly. In this project I only have viewOne, viewTwo and a button to control this. There is also a boolean called "blue".

```
@IBAction func bttn() {
        if blue {
            blue = false
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                self.viewOne.frame.size.height = 64
            }
        }else {
            blue =  true
            self.viewOne.frame.size.height = 100
        }
    }
```

When I tap the button I expect viewOne to increase in size and viewTwo to be moved down since there is a constraint between the top and bottom of the views.

But the actual result is that viewOne increase but viewTwo does not move.

Answer (score 1):

Only autolayout can do this  as changing frames doesn't apply the constraints , You need to create a height outlet for view1 then

```
self.view1Height.constant = 64
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```